# How to get everyone to remove the git branch locally that has been removed from origin

Tags: git, branch

Every once in a while our team tries to clean up branches from origin that are no longer relevant, but many of these branches re-surface as other team members do push --all (I think) and the branches make their way back to the origin. Is there any way to remove a branch and have it not be pushed to origin again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Ask them to not use `git push -a`. It's kind of a workflow problem, not a git problem. You can't really force anyone to remove a branch from their repo. You should all agree on it.

Comment: push -a is convenient and allows one to push changes to multiple branches. Not fair to ask people to not use this command. There must be a way to get git to clear all removed remote branches before pushing.

Comment: You can push to multiple branches in a single shot without pulling out the big gun (`git push -a`): `git push the-remote branch1 branch2 branch3 branchX`.